# PHP Login not working?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, crypt

So I am making a login script, but it doesn't seems to work. (It always says that the username/password is wrong.

Here is the script:

```
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
Include('config.php');

$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=($_POST['mypassword']);


$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);

$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);

$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);

$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$mypassword = crypt($mypassword);


$sql="SELECT id FROM members WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";

$result=mysql_query($sql);



$count=mysql_num_rows($result);


if($count==1){



echo  'lol';

}
else {

echo "Wrong Username or Password";

}

}

else

{

echo 'You did not post anything';

}
```

By the way on the register, I used crypt()

```
$pa = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['pass']);

$pass = crypt($pa);
```

My script is supposed to echo lol (as a test) but it keeps saying that my username/password is wrong.

EDIT: I will change the mysql_ to mysqli_

EDIT 2: Form:

```
    <br>
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="logging.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong><center>Member Login</center> </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="78">Username</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="mypassword" type="text" id="mypassword"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<tr>
```

Comment: You are wide open to injection and your API is deprecated.

Comment: @TheBlueDog its true that `mysql_` is deprecated but its not broken

Comment: your html form......??

Comment: @TheBlueDog Can you tell me how I could prevent injection? And thank you for your help.

Comment: @andrew: How is it not broken? It can't handle prepared statements, it can't do transactions, it's not being maintained and it emits an `E_DEPRECATED` notice on version 5.4 and up. It ***is*** like a broken pencil: completely and utterly pointless. using it to write new code is a crime.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I'm not saying that `mysql_` should be used,on the contrary, just that doing so doesn't necessarily leave you "wide open to injection"

Answer (score 1):

`crypt()` will return a different hash each time it is called ([see for yourself](http://codepad.org/pNri568Q)), so you cannot simply use `==` to compare them. What you can do, is use [`hash_equals()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-equals.php) like this (if you have PHP 5.6+)

```
$sql = "SELECT id, password FROM members WHERE username='$myusername'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
//check if 1 row exists
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

if (hash_equals($row['password'], $mypassword)) {
    //correct password
}
```

For this to properly work, you need to make sure that each `username` exists only once in the db, this is easily done via the `UNIQUE` constraint

Answer (score 1):

`crypt()` function return different value with each call if you did not pass any salt

try this:

```
$pa = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['pass']);
$salt="aaaa"; //you must make it complex string
$pass = crypt($pa,$salt);
```

and check it by login as:

```
$salt="aaaa"; //same salt as above
$mypassword = crypt($mypassword,$salt);

$sql="SELECT id FROM members WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
```

[See Here](https://eval.in/210094)